# Tutte's theorem - How does assuming a maximal graph prove the theorem true for non-maximal graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

From **Introduction to Graph Theory** by West:

> A graph $G$ has a $1$-factor if and only if $o(G - S) \le |S|$ for every $S \subseteq V(G)$ where $o(G)$ means the number of odd components of $G$.

Tutte shows:

> $(1.)$ If $G' = G + e$ and $G$ satisfies Tutte's condition, then $G'$ also satisfies Tutte's condition.

and

> $(2.)$  If $G'$ has no $1$-factor, then $G$ has no $1$-factor.

He then proceeds to prove sufficiency by stating "the theorem holds unless there exists a simple graph $G$ such that $G$ satisfies Tutte's condition, $G$ has no $1$-factor, and adding any missing edge to $G$ yields a graph with a $1$-factor".  He then proceeds to obtain a contradiction by showing that $G$ actually contains a $1$-factor.

What I don't understand is:

How does this show that for any graph $G$ that satisfies Tutte's condition it must have a $1$-factor?  This just seems to show:  If $G$ is a graph that satisfies Tutte's conditions, and $G'$ is the maximal graph created from $G$, then $G'$ has a $1$-matching.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $G$ satisfies the theorem's conditions but does not have a $1$-factor. We know that:

- We can keep adding edges to $G$ to get a maximal graph $G'$ that doesn't have a $1$-factor, but is such that by adding any other edge anywhere it will have a $1$-factor.
- $G'$ satisfies the theorem's conditions (since adding edges preserves them).
- The proof shows that a graph with properties of $G'$ cannot exist.

So we reach a contradiction and we conclude that the original graph $G$ must have a $1$-factor.